# What I can use to waterproof a sink cutout

Tags: wood, kitchens, woodworking, waterproofing, countertops

I'm using solid wood to make a worktop/countertop in my camper van. It's going to have an undermounted sink, so I need to use something to protect the edge of the sink cutout from water. I have no idea what product to use and can't find a good solution anywhere.

Comment: Have you considered a self-rimming sink? Aside from the difficulty of creating a durable cut edge, undermounts are prone to failing in static settings -- never mind a mobile camper.

Answer (score 1):

Danish oil, tung oil, linseed oil will work if you apply multiple coats and re-apply on a regular basis. There are also special formulations with additives (waxes) that increase water and chemical resistance (but are usually less impact resistant).

Varnish will work as well, is more prone to mechanical damage, but does not have to be re-applied unless damaged or worn down.

Spar varnish (or outdoor varnish) is usually more resistant to UV and water, but will also usually emit more harmful fumes.

Solvent-based varnishes will in general be more durable and easier to apply than water-based varnishes. Water-based varnishes are generally healthier (less emissions and toxic fumes).

Most danish oils are food safe and will increase the hardness of the surface (offer better impact protection).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have fitted a sink (surface mount) I have **always** varnished the edges of the hole I cut for the sink to go into. So, any water that does get past the seal just tends to drip down instead of getting absorbed.

I would make sure the hole has smoothed edges and varnish, or equivalent sealing, as appropriate to prevent the edges absorbing water and bulging over time.

Comment: @isherwood just re-read the OP’s question which seems to lack the word varnish... the last worktop instructions I read also used the word « varnish » for sealing cut edges and they did not specify a make...

Comment: @isherwood first paragraph uses the word "varnished" and the second paragraph uses the word "varnish" with "or equivalent sealing", so not sure why you find it unclear about me suggesting **varnish**...